# bash script command output execution doesn't assign full output when using backticks

Tags: bash

I used many times [``] to capture output of command to a variable. but with following code i am not getting right output.

```
#!/bin/bash
export XLINE='($ZWP_SCRIP_NAME),$ZWP_LT_RSI_TRIGGER)R),$ZWP_RTIMER'
echo 'Original XLINE'
echo $XLINE 
echo '------------------'
echo 'Extract all word with $ZWP'
#works fine
echo $XLINE  | sed -e 's/\$/\n/g' | sed -e 's/.*\(ZWP[_A-Z]*\).*/\1/g'  | grep ZWP
echo '------------------'
echo 'Assign all word with $ZWP to XVAR'
#XVAR doesn't get all the values
export XVAR=`echo $XLINE  | sed -e 's/\$/\n/g' | sed -e 's/.*\(ZWP[_A-Z]*\).*/\1/g' | grep ZWP` #fails
echo "$XVAR"
```

and i get:

```
Original XLINE
($ZWP_SCRIP_NAME),$ZWP_LT_RSI_TRIGGER)R),$ZWP_RTIMER
------------------
Extract all word with $ZWP
ZWP_SCRIP_NAME
ZWP_LT_RSI_TRIGGER
ZWP_RTIMER
------------------
Assign all word with $ZWP to XVAR
ZWP_RTIMER
```

why XVAR doesn't get all the values?

however if i use $() to capture the out instead of ``, it works fine. but why `` is not working?

Comment: There are really two different questions here -- one, why your original code didn't work, and two, how to actually accomplish your goal correctly. There's no need to use `sed` or `grep` here at all.

Comment: ...and you don't need `export` either, unless you want your subprocesses to have access to your variables. And using all-caps names for your own variables contravenes POSIX convention (see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html)

Comment: BTW, `sed -e 's/\$/\n/g' ` doesn't do what you think it does. Frankly, `tr '$' '\n'` would be a better alternative.

Comment: Several of the mistakes here are covered in the [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).  I suggest you review it.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: shellcheck.net seems a good place for automated review. thanks for sharing.

Comment: The backticks _should_ work the same as $(), but in strange ways they don't. Here is a simpler example showing a case where backticks don't work as expected: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1293395

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having GNU grep you can use this command:

```
XVAR=$(grep -oP '\$\KZWP[A-Z_]+' <<< "$XLINE")
```

If you pass `-P` grep is using Perl compatible regular expressions. The key here is the `\K` escape sequence. Basically the regex matches `$ZWP` followed by one or more uppercase characters or underscores. The `\K` after the `$` removes the `$` itself from the match, while its presence is still required to match the whole pattern. Call it poor man's lookbehind if you want, I like it! :)

Btw, `grep -o` outputs every match on a single line instead of just printing the lines which match the pattern.

If you don't have GNU grep or you care about portability you can use `awk`, like this:

```
XVAR=$(awk -F'$' '{sub(/[^A-Z_].*/, "", $2); print $2}' RS=',' <<< "$XLINE")
```

Comment: What are you doing here that depends on `-P`? Strikes me as completely needless reliance on a newer version of GNU grep than otherwise would be necessary. (OTOH, if you used a negative lookbehind to exclude the `$`, that would make sense).

Comment: You're still using `-o` and `-P`, both of those GNUisms, in the latter form. Might at least change the latter to `-E` to support older GNU grep.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, sorry. I just missed that.

Comment: Being able to backslash-escape ERE syntax (ie. `\+`) to use them in BREs is actually a nonportable extension too; better to use `-E`.

Comment: Oh, never knew. But `\{1,\}` should be portable, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that one's explicitly part of BRE.

Comment: Thanks Charles and hek2mgl. It helped!

Answer (score 1):

First, the smallest change that makes your code "work":

```
echo "$XLINE" | tr '$' '\n' | sed -e 's/.*\(ZWP[_A-Z]*\).*/\1/g' | grep ZWP_
```

The use of `tr` replaces a sed expression that didn't actually do what you thought it did -- try looking at its output to see.

---

One sane alternative would be to rely on GNU grep's `-o` option. If you can't do that...

```
zwpvars=( )                                     # create a shell array
zwp_assignment_re='[$](ZWP_[[:alnum:]_]+)(.*)'  # ...and a regex
content="$XLINE"
while [[ $content =~ $zwp_assignment_re ]]; do
  zwpvars+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )             # found a reference
  content=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}                    # stuff the remaining content aside
done

printf 'Found variable: %s\n' "${zwpvars[@]}"
```

Comment: `echo "$XLINE"  | sed -e 's/\$/\n/g'` seems to work OK for me ...replaces the '$' characters with newlines.

Comment: @MarkkuK., doesn't work for me -- maybe we were testing against different implementations of `sed`.

Comment: Excellent call about the backticks impacting backslash interpretation, btw.